# How to save multiple tabs from workbook to a new workbook and save it with a new name and break the link

Tags: excel, vba, copy

new to this all! please help, when I run this macro, it goes through, but it opens a new workbook has the tabs I need but doesn't rename it or save it to the destination folder I need it to? Run time error 424 pops up. Also is there a code I can add at the end to break the link from the workbook it came from?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copysheetandsave()
    Dim sourceWs As Worksheet, savePath As String

    Set sourceWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("S&M", "400", "410")).Copy

    savePath = "C:\Users\"

    sourceWs.Copy
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=savePath & "YTD 2023 YTD.xlsx"
         .Close False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What's kind of `link`?

Answer (score 0):

### Export Sheets and Break Links

- There are worksheets and charts (objects). They are part of the `Workbook.Sheets` collection.
- There is a `Worksheet` object and a `Chart` object but **no** `Sheet` object.
- If you want to reference sheets using an array of their names, you can declare such an object as a `Sheets` object (or the generic `Object` object), **not** a `Worksheet(s)` object.
- You cannot append a `.Copy` e.g. `Set a = b.Copy` since it is a method, not a property (similarly you cannot do `Set ws = wb.Sheets(1).Copy(After:=...)`. On the other hand, you can do `Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add`.).

**Main**

```vb
Sub ExportSheetsToNewWorkbook()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Export Sheets To New Workbook"
    Dim Success As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const DST_PATH As String = "C:\Users\"
    Const DST_NAME As String = "YTD 2023 YTD.xlsx"
    Const DST_FORMAT As Long = xlOpenXMLWorkbook ' 51
    Dim sSheetNames() As Variant: sSheetNames = Array("S&M", "400", "410")
    
    ' Build the destination file path.
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = DST_PATH
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & pSep
    Dim dFilePath As String: dFilePath = dFolderPath & DST_NAME
    
    ' Copy the source sheets to a new workbook, the destination workbook.
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sshs As Sheets: Set sshs = swb.Sheets(sSheetNames)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sshs.Copy
    
    ' Reference the destination workbook.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
    ' Break all links to the source workbook.
    BreakLinksToAnotherWorkbook dwb, swb
    
    ' Save the destination workbook.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
    dwb.SaveAs Filename:=dFilePath, FileFormat:=DST_FORMAT
    
    Success = True
    
ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent endless loop if error in continuation
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        ' Close the destination workbook.
        If Not dwb Is Nothing Then dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        ' Inform.
        If Success Then MsgBox "Sheets exported.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

**Help - Break Links to Another Workbook**

```vb
Sub BreakLinksToAnotherWorkbook( _
        ByVal wb As Workbook, _
        ByVal wbLinked As Workbook)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Break Links to Another Workbook"
    
    Dim LinkNames As Variant: LinkNames = wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    If IsEmpty(LinkNames) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim LinkedFilePath As String: LinkedFilePath = wbLinked.FullName
    
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, ErrNumber As Long
    
    For n = 1 To UBound(LinkNames)
        If StrComp(LinkNames(n), LinkedFilePath, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
                wb.BreakLink LinkNames(n), xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
                ErrNumber = Err.Number
            On Error GoTo 0
            If ErrNumber <> 0 Then
                MsgBox "Could not break the links to """ & LinkedFilePath _
                    & """!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            End If
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next n
        
End Sub
```

**Bonus - Break Excel Links (not used)**

```vb
Sub BreakExcelLinks(ByVal wb As Workbook)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Break Excel Links"
    
    Dim LinkNames As Variant: LinkNames = wb.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    If IsEmpty(LinkNames) Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, ErrNumber As Long
    
    For n = 1 To UBound(LinkNames)
        On Error Resume Next
            wb.BreakLink LinkNames(n), xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
            ErrNumber = Err.Number
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ErrNumber <> 0 Then
            i = i + 1
            LinkNames(i) = LinkNames(n)
        End If
    Next n
    
    If i = 0 Then Exit Sub
    If i < n - 1 Then ReDim Preserve LinkNames(1 To i)
    
    MsgBox "Could not break the links to the following files:" _
        & vbLf & vbLf & Join(LinkNames, vbLf), vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        
End Sub
```